# Create several similar Angular dialogs without lots of code and templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using the modal module of Angular UI to create dialog boxes. I need to create several boxes which are quite similar. They look roughly like this:

```
Question?
yes (yellow button), no, cancel

Question?
yes (yellow button), no

cancel
    option 1
    option 2 (yellow button)
    option 3
```

Is there a smart way I can avoid having to create HTML templates for each individual dialog? In other languages I would do something like "result = showDialog("Question?", ["ok", "cancel"])". I want to avoid putting things in my controller that should really not be there though (e.g. presentation stuff).

By the way, I don't get to decide how the UI looks by the way so they must look like this...

Comment: if the question is "is there", the answer is "yes"... but you will not accept that because you will need an example... =)

Comment: create a service that wraps the modal code

Comment: @fstr, I see you're new here, so welcome! You might want to read up on some of the site etiquette around asking questions and, more specifically, receiving answers. You're not obligated to accept an answer, but you should definitely interact with the answers you've got (ask for clarification if needed, state issues with provided solutions, etc). Here's a little reading on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single template and a single controller that would handle all of these scenarios, just applying different options through the controller:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, options) {    
  $scope.options = options;

  $scope.yes = function () {
    $modalInstance.close('yes');
  };

  $scope.no = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('no');
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Then wrap the call to that modal inside a function that can be called wherever you need it:

```
  $scope.showDialog = function (question, title, showCancel) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        options: function () {
          return {
            question: question,
            title: title,
            showCancel: showCancel
          };
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (action) {
      $scope.selected = action;
    }, function (action) {
      $scope.selected = action;
    });
};
```

Then a modal template that displays whatever you need based on the options passed in. Here's a plunker demonstrating the idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/y3c5bz5AXjrNo1XFzMBP

Of course, if you are going to use such a thing throughout your application, it would be wise to abstract it out into a service, rather than have it be a function attached to `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

Within a single html template, create multiple buttons, and in conjunction with custom options, show or hide the buttons using ng-show. Example: ng-show="showButton3".